# Python: Get library path before importing

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, operating-system, filesystems

I would like to get the path of a library before importing the library itself.

That is, something different from:

```
import module, os
library_path = os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
```

Is that possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `imp` module:

```
import imp
file_handle, module_path, module_doc = imp.find_module(module_name)
```

The second return value is the path to actual file (assuming there is one, since requested module could be a built-in). First parameter is a file handle, already opened for you.

For as long as your use case is simple, you shouldn't have any issues. If you'll try for a generic solution you will need to read `imp` module documentation carefully, as there are lots of possible situations and return values for this function.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import commands
print commands.__file__

/usr/lib/python2.7/commands.py

import os
print os.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
```

Yes you can, but all modules doesn't support  __ file__